# Перезапуск функции в Aiogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Есть такой код, обрабатывающий команду от тг-бота:

```
# обрабатываем команду "/check_out"
@dp.message_handler(commands=['check_out'])
@auth
async def send_text_file_to_bot(message: types.Message):

    # Запуск скрипта и получение его вывода
    output = subprocess.check_output(['python', 'LIB/checkout.py'])
    
    # Импорт переменной logname
    from LIB.checkout import logname

    # Отправка файла в чат с тг-ботом
    await message.reply_document(open(logname, 'rb'))
```

**checkout.py** - питоновский файл, делающий запрос в БД и сохраняющий результат этого запроса в логе (обычный текстовый файл) с динамическим уникальным именем. Имя хранится и передаёся через переменную **logname**

Функция отрабатывает корректно, но при повторной отправке команды функция берет уже имеющееся имя файла и отправляет повторно тот же файл, минуя всю предыдущую логику (запуск питоновского файла и импорт переменной).

Подскажите, как это можно исправить?
Обнуление переменной `logname = None` ни в начале функции, ни в начале вызываемого файла не помогло.

Comment: checkout.py ассинхронный?

Comment: Не совсем понятен вопрос, если честно. 
Обычный файл, код библиотеки Asincio в нем не используется.

Comment: У вас в декораторе функция асинхронная, вот и стоит вопрос, асинхронный ли chechout.py, к которому обращаются?

Comment: Чем асинхронный питоновский файл отличается от обычного? Какие есть признаки?

Comment: Судя по гуглению понятия "асинхронный питоновский файл", можно утверждать, что checkout.py не является асинхронным.